# scala: Is collection object mutable?

Tags: scala, collections

this question has no functional value. Just trying to get a better understanding of scala.
All collections inherent [Iterable](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Iterable.html). There is no `isMutable` method in Iterable.
Soliciting input on whether the below `isMutable` is the most efficient to assess mutability. It seems archaic but couldn't find an alternative other than testing for all mutable collection classes which is not ideal since new mutable classes could be added in the future. (I would define the method using `implicit` but didn't for simplicity).

```
import scala.collection.{immutable, mutable}

object IsMutable extends App {
  val mutableMap: mutable.Map[String, Int] = mutable.Map("Apples" -> 4,"Pineapples" -> 1,"Oranges" -> 10,"Grapes" -> 7)
  val immutableMap: immutable.Map[String, Int] = Map("Apples" -> 4,"Pineapples" -> 1,"Oranges" -> 10,"Grapes" -> 7)

  def isMutable[A](obj: Iterable[A]): Boolean = obj.getClass.toString.startsWith("class scala.collection.mutable")

  println(isMutable(mutableMap))
  println(isMutable(immutableMap))
}
```

Comment: I did not quite understand your question, it's not clear enough what you're looking for, at least to me. `collection` is not an object, it's a package. basically the hierarchy of scala collection looks like this, the `scala.collection` package, root of both either mutable or immutable collection types such as `Iterable`, `List`, etc,. `scala.collection.mutable`, which has all the types inside `scala.collection`, same thing goes for `scala.collection.immutable`.

Comment: Given an arbitrary input param, myMap, how would you determine whether this input collection is mutable or not?

Comment: Why would you want to do that ? Just check if you can modify them or not. If you can modify them then they are mutable, else not.

Comment: What is the purpose of this? Abstracting over collections is usually a meaningless idea.

Comment: "no functional value" –– that is your answer. 
Mutability is a meta–concept. There is no way to tell if something is "mutable" at runtime ... nor there's any need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AminMal's idea if fine. Mutable collections do extend `mutable.Iterable`, so checking if your collection is an instance of it is self-explanatory.

As an alternative way: mutable collections inherit 2 specific traits that allow them to be mutated internally: `Growable` and `Shrinkable`. `Growable` means a collection can be augmented using the `+=` operator, while `Shrinkable` means it can be reduced using the `-=` operator.

On a side note, there is a trick to use these operators on immutable collections too: your reference must be declared using `var` to support reassignment. With mutable collections, though, you don't need reassignment, because these operations are supported by the 2 traits mentioned, which is why mutable collections can be declared using `val`.

Checking if your collection is an instance of either one of these 2 traits means it is mutable:

```
val myMap: mutable.Map[String, Int] = mutable.Map(
    "Apples" -> 4,
    "Pineapples" -> 1,
    "Oranges" -> 10,
    "Grapes" -> 7
  )
  val mySet: mutable.Set[Int] = mutable.Set(1, 2, 3)

  val myMap2: Map[String, Int] = Map(
    "Apples" -> 4,
    "Pineapples" -> 1,
    "Oranges" -> 10,
    "Grapes" -> 7
  )
  val mySet2: Set[Int] = Set(1, 2, 3)

  println(myMap.isInstanceOf[mutable.Growable[_]])       // true
  println(myMap2.isInstanceOf[mutable.Shrinkable[_]])    // false
  println(mySet.isInstanceOf[mutable.Shrinkable[_]])     // true
  println(mySet2.isInstanceOf[mutable.Shrinkable[_]])    // false
```

Answer (score 3):

I think relying on the class name is not a good approach, although I believe, that the approach I'm proposing is not probably the most elegant/best way to find out if a collection is mutable or not. But you can use this:

```scala
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

def isMutable[T](iterable: scala.collection.Iterable[T]): Boolean = 
  iterable.isInstanceOf[scala.collection.mutable.Iterable[T]]
```

I think it would work fine for most of the types (the weird interface below is because I'm using ammonite as REPL, which is pretty cool :D).

```scala
@ val immutableMap = scala.collection.immutable.Map[String, String]() 
immutableMap: Map[String, String] = Map()

@ isMutable(immutableMap) 
res14: Boolean = false

@ val mutableMap = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, String]() 
mutableMap: mutable.Map[String, String] = HashMap()

@ isMutable(mutableMap) 
res16: Boolean = true
```